# Is there a way to access/calculate the percentage of disk fragmentation in Java?

Tags: java, windows

Thinking in a similar fashion as JavaSysMon, is there a way to get the % of disk fragmentation on a Windows OS?  Or possibly a method to calculate this based on analyzing the file system.  And for clarification, I am not speaking in terms of the JVM heap fragmentation, I am referring to the actual disk fragmentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to do this in pure Java.  Furthermore, such an API would be necessarily operating system specific, and of no utility to all but a tiny number of programmers.  So don't expect Oracle to add such an API any time soon.

Your best bet is to look for some Windows compatible command-line utility that does the job, and use `System.exec(...)` or similar to run it from your Java application.